# LinkNode D1 Serial stops working when using pinMode

Tags: esp8266

The following code works. I get an output in the console every second of "Hello" and then the `analogValue` of the photoresistor.

```
int greenLedPin = D1;
int yellowLedPin = D2;
int redLedPin = D3;

int lightSensorPin = A0;
int analogValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
//  pinMode(greenLedPin, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(yellowLedPin, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(redLedPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  analogValue = analogRead(lightSensorPin);
  Serial.println("Hello.");
  Serial.println(analogValue);
  delay(1000);
//  digitalWrite(greenLedPin, HIGH);
//  digitalWrite(yellowLedPin, HIGH);
//  digitalWrite(redLedPin, HIGH);
}
```

Now as soon as I uncomment the `pinMode` commands nothing shows up on the console.

```
int greenLedPin = D1;
int yellowLedPin = D2;
int redLedPin = D3;

int lightSensorPin = A0;
int analogValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(greenLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLedPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  analogValue = analogRead(lightSensorPin);
  Serial.println("Hello.");
  Serial.println(analogValue);
  delay(1000);
//  digitalWrite(greenLedPin, HIGH);
//  digitalWrite(yellowLedPin, HIGH);
//  digitalWrite(redLedPin, HIGH);
}
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Does it happen when only one of the Dn pins is uncommented?  (I'm thinking the definition of Dn might be to the wrong GPIO pin)  - I'll test you code when I get home to see if I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Move **int greenLedPin = D1;** and **int redLedPin = D3;** to another pin, because D1 and D3 is Tx and Rx.

[image]

http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/reference.html

Comment: Would plugging things into the D1 and D3 pins like LEDs cause this sort of weirdness to happen? My problem eventually became the chip completely ignoring any changes in my sketch. Editing the sketch or even uploading a completely different sketch resulted in the chip simply running the same old code every time.

Comment: FYI here is an image of the LinkNode D1: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-seller-content-images-us-east-1/ATVPDKIKX0DER/A2TOL213PF2CAG/B01DD641G6/pdmYH3IESLKD._UX970_TTW__.png

D1 is marked as "TX->D1" and D2 is "D2" and D3 is "D15/SCL/D3", so D3 isn't RX0

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/linksprite/Linknode+D1/LinkNode-D1-sch.pdf

Shows pin 15, 16 (D1, D3) is connected to the USB/Serial IC.

And YES, the old code interrupts the upload of the new code. A solution is to press the reset button before the Arduino IDE shows "Upload code", this will put the ESP-12 into programming mode.

Comment: I actually did hit the reset button right after compiling but before the IDE showed Upload Code. Same result.

Comment: Sorry the correct procedure is: Connect LinkNode D1 to your PC. Press and hold the Reset button, and then Connect D8 (Flash) to ground (GND). Release the Reset button, and then disconnect D8 from ground. And now its in programming mode.